# How to get a song to play automatically in WxPython MediaCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython, media

I am making a music player and everything goes well except when I click the next button, it loads the next song, but wont play it unless the user presses the play button. Is there anyway to make this play automatically just by hitting the next button and not having to press the play button afterwards. I have tried binding the play function and the load function to the button and that did not work, I have also tried just including mc.Play() in my load function, but that does not work either.

Here is my code:

```
import wx
import wx.media
import os

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Music Player',size=(900,670),style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        bg = wx.Image('bg.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bg, (0,0))
        panel = wx.Panel(self,style=wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

        ##MENU AND STATUS BAR
        self.status = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.status.SetStatusText('Ready')
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file_menu = wx.Menu()
        view_menu = wx.Menu()
        controls_menu = wx.Menu()
        help_menu = wx.Menu()

        #MENU ID'S
        ID_FILE_LOAD = 2
        ID_FILE_EXIT = 3

        ID_VIEW_SHOW_STATUSBAR = 4

        ID_CONTROLS_PLAY = 5
        ID_CONTROLS_PAUSE = 6
        ID_CONTROLS_STOP = 7

        ID_HELP_ABOUT = 8

        ##FILE MENU
        file_menu.Append(ID_FILE_LOAD, "&Load...\tCtrl+L", "This will let you choose a song to load")
        file_menu.AppendSeparator()
        file_menu.Append(ID_FILE_EXIT,"Exit","This will exit the program")

        ##VIEW MENU
        self.check_statusbar = view_menu.Append(ID_VIEW_SHOW_STATUSBAR,'Show Stat&usbar\tCtrl+U', "This will disable the statusbar", kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        view_menu.Check(self.check_statusbar.GetId(), True)

        ##CONTROLS MENU
        controls_menu.Append(ID_CONTROLS_PLAY,"&Play\tEnter", "Play the selected song")
        controls_menu.Append(ID_CONTROLS_PAUSE,"&Pause\tSpace", "Pause the selected song")

        ##MENUBAR APPEND
        menubar.Append(file_menu,"File")
        menubar.Append(view_menu,"View")
        menubar.Append(controls_menu,"Controls")
        menubar.Append(help_menu,"Help")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        ##MENU ACTION BINDING
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Load, None, 2)        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Close, None, 3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.ToggleStatusBar, self.check_statusbar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Play, None, 5)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Pause, None, 6)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.About, None, 8)

        ##FONTS
        font1 = wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        font2 = wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)

        try:
            self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self)
        except NotImplementedError:
            raise

        ##BUTTONS

        bttnprt = self.bitmap1

        loadButton = wx.Button(bttnprt, -1, "Load File...", pos=(308,435), size=(281,31))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Load, loadButton)

        playButton = wx.Button(bttnprt, -1, "Play", pos=(458,491), size=(57,57))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Play, playButton)

        pauseButton = wx.Button(bttnprt, -1, "Pause", pos=(383,491), size=(57,57))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Pause, pauseButton)

        volumeUpButton = wx.Button(bttnprt, -1, "Up", pos=(400,299), size=(95,52))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSetVolumeUp, volumeUpButton)

        volumeDownButton = wx.Button(bttnprt, -1, "Down", pos=(400,363), size=(95,52))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSetVolumeDown, volumeDownButton)

        backButton = wx.Button(bttnprt, -1, "Back", pos=(308,491), size=(57,57))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.previousSong, backButton)

        nextButton = wx.Button(bttnprt, -1, "Next", pos=(533,491), size=(57,57))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.nextSong, nextButton)

        self.volumeCtrl = wx.Slider(bttnprt, value=50, minValue=0, maxValue=100, style=wx.SL_VERTICAL|wx.SL_INVERSE, pos=(300,300))
#        self.volumeCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.onSetVolume)
        self.volumeCtrl.Hide()

        songlist = os.listdir('songs')
        self.myListBox = listbox = wx.ListBox(bttnprt, -1, (301,80), (296,206), songlist, wx.LB_SINGLE)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.selLoadFile, listbox)

#        self.st_file = wx.StaticText(bttnprt, -1, "Blank", pos=(30,30))

        def newWin(self, event):
            self.new = NewWindow(parent=self, id=-1)
            self.new.Show()

    def Close(self, event):
        box=wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Are you sure you want to exit?', 'Exit program?', wx.YES_NO)
        answer=box.ShowModal()
        if answer==wx.ID_YES:
            self.Destroy()

    def About(self, event):
        self.new = AboutWindow(parent=self, id=-1)
        self.new.Show()

    def selLoadFile(self, event):
            my_selection = self.myListBox.GetStringSelection()
            file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"songs",my_selection)
            self.doLoadFile2(file_path)

    def Load(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a media file", "songs", "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.doLoadFile(path)
            dlg.Destroy() 

    def load2(self):
            my_selection = self.myListBox.GetStringSelection()
            file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"songs",my_selection)
            self.doLoadFile2(file_path)
            self.mc.Play()

    def doLoadFile(self, path):
        if not self.mc.Load(path):
            wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % path, "ERROR", wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)

        else:
            folder, filename = os.path.split(path)
            self.mc.SetBestFittingSize()
            self.mc.Play()

    def doLoadFile2(self, file_path):
        if not self.mc.Load(file_path):
            wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % file_path, "ERROR", wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)

        else:
            folder, filename = os.path.split(file_path)
            #self.st_file.SetLabel('%s' % filename)
            self.status.SetStatusText("Now Playing: " +'%s' % filename)
            self.mc.SetBestFittingSize()
            self.mc.Play()

    def Play(self, event):
        self.mc.Play()

    def Pause(self, event):
        self.mc.Pause()

    def onSetVolumeUp(self, event):

        self.currentVolume = self.volumeCtrl.GetValue()
        self.newVolumeAdd = self.currentVolume + 1.5
        self.volumeCtrl.SetValue(self.newVolumeAdd)

        self.mc.SetVolume(float(self.currentVolume) / 100)

    def onSetVolumeDown(self, event):
        self.currentVolume = self.volumeCtrl.GetValue()
        self.newVolumeSub = self.currentVolume - 1.5
        self.volumeCtrl.SetValue(self.newVolumeSub)

        self.mc.SetVolume(float(self.currentVolume) / 100)

    def previousSong(self, event):
        current = self.myListBox.GetSelection()
        new = current - 1
        self.myListBox.SetSelection(new)
        self.mc.Stop()
        self.load2()

    def nextSong(self, event):
        current = self.myListBox.GetSelection()
        new = current + 1
        self.myListBox.SetSelection(new)
        self.mc.Stop()
        self.load2()

    def ToggleStatusBar(self, e):
        if self.check_statusbar.IsChecked():
            self.status.Show()
            self.status.SetStatusText('Ready')
        else:
            self.status.Hide()

        ##RUN##

if __name__=='__main__':
        app=wx.PySimpleApp()
        frame=MainWindow(parent=None,id=-1)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: try to call `play()` from EVT_MEDIA_LOADED event handler (bind it first)

Answer (score 2):

If this is windows, and possibly specifically Win 7, 64bit, you need to do 2 things to get this to work.

1. As J.F. Sebastian mentioned, you need to call the play from a method that is bound to the EVT_MEDIA_LOADED event.  The [docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxmediactrl.html#wxmediactrlcreate) actually mention this.
2. Specify a backend when you create the MediaCtrl.  I'm not sure why its needed, but it didn't work for me until I did that.

So try the following changes:

```
...
#change this existing line
self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10)
...
# add this new line
self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.song_is_loaded)
...
# add this new method
def song_is_loaded(self, event):
    self.mc.Play()
```

You can also remove all the self.mc.Play() calls now except the one in the Play() function itself (since loading the file will now cause it to play).

I also noticed you've defined a bunch of ID_XXX constants, but then just used numbers when you bound your menu buttons.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using windows vista 32-bit, I will give this a try though! Thanks!